# Is it Possible with out creating a webview we can view the web page

Tags: objective-c

Is this possible with out using a webview we can view the web page in our view

Comment: Well, you could write an HTML renderer for yourself.

Comment: Your question is confusing but from the comments below I see your intentions. What you really want to ask is if you can interact with a website (login,pull information,etc..) without using a UIWebView. The answer is yes if they provide an API like facebook does, or if you scrape the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to build your own HTML renderer (almost rebuilding a browser) then i suppose not. My advice is to use a UIWebView or the browser installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply    but i want to access without using the webview

Comment: Ok then you will have to make your own HTML renderer or find one somewhere on the net. That will be a lot of work.

Comment: For Example if i want to login my Facebook with out using the webview.I roam around the net there s an oAuth for authenticating.May i know how it s working.

Comment: Oh well that is possible, you just ask for username and password, save those and log in to facebook and get an XML feed. this should be possible for both objective-c and Android. [Information about Facebook usage in apps](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/).